# AngularJS apply class on change in ng-repeat with pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pagination

I'm trying to apply a class to an item in a paginated list ,for that I just simulate a click on the element in the directive link property :

```
link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function () {
        element.addClass("blue");
            });

}
```

This is working well,but The problem I have is that when I move for example from the first page to the second,I loose the classes I applied to the items on the first page.
How I can keep all those items with the class I applied before.

Thank You.

[A plunker to better understand](http://plnkr.co/edit/jbDYRmi0rsxeOT8cWsui?p=preview)

Comment: The plunker wasn't working for me. Missing the file dirPagination.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to bind the class to a property of an element using ng-class and set the item property through ng-click, instead of using a directive.

```
<input type="text" 
  ng-init="oldValueName = item.name" 
  ng-change="change($index,item.name,oldValueName,item.id,'name')" 
  ng-model="item.name" 

  ng-class="{'blue': item.nameClicked}"
  ng-click="item.nameClicked = true"
/>
```

If your data is persistent, the classes will be applied automatically when you move through the pages.

For more information on ng-class and ng-click

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

and

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing the change in the data rather than the element in the directive.

```
$scope.items = [
  {id: 51,name: 'Hello',surname: 'other454r', highlight: false},
  {id: 52,name: 'Foobar',surname: 'othe44rr' highlight: false},
  {id: 53,name: 'Barfoo',surname: 'othe52rr' highlight: false},
  {id: 54,name: 'Magic',surname: 'other1r' highlight: false},
  {id: 55,name: 'Wand',surname: 'other4r' highlight: false}
];
```

Then in your repeat you can use the angular `ng-click` and `ng-class` directives which would look something like the following:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items"
    ng-click="item.highlight=!item.highlight"
    ng-class="{'blue': item.highlight}">
  {{item.name + ' ' + item.surname}}
</span>
```